# How to show with induction that $A(x) = A'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

If we have the the formal power series $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \cdot x^k$ and his generating function $A(x) = e^x$. How to show with induction, that $A(x) = A'(x)$?

First of all I tried it with the formal power series, but I think this isn't the right method to do this. Is it possible to induce about the derivate from a generating function.

Comment: You can differentiate term-by-term since the series converges uniformly on compact sets.

Comment: Why do you call it a formal power series? Assuming you mean it belongs to the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ or $\mathbb{R}[x]$, how do you define derivative? I don't think you have any choice but to differentiate and compare term by term which necessarily involves induction (albeit in a trivial way).

Answer (score 2):

Just derive the series term by term!

Comment: Slight nitpick: use the word "differentiate", not "derive" in this context.